# Is this network implementation possible at all?

Tags: networking, vpn, router, vlan

I'm currently working on a machine we will ship to many customers over the world that needs to connect to a single server, this is currently done over the internet but i'm thinking it would be easier for remote management to have them be on my network over a VPN.

While i know how to make a vpn between each client and my Datacenter i don't know if the following is possible at all and if so how:

- Have a vpn capable router at each client
- Have a single vpn router in our Datacenter
- Have n (1 per client) vpn connections
- Have those multiple connections on separate vlans so that those customers network can't communicate together
  (up untill there i know how to do all that)
- Have the server somehow "be" on the sum of all those vlans from a single NIC (is it possible to create a vlan that encompasses multiple other vlans or Something similar? Am i taking the wrong path completely?)

Comment: What kind of hardware are you working with or are you looking for a theoretical answer.

Comment: @JacobEvans I'm happy to pick the hardware based on the answers i get if needed. Currently there is no hardware picked on the datacenter side and a cisco rv 325 on testing for the machine side (happy with any gigabit ethernet router that is silent and reliable and supports dhcp which leaves me with well, pretty much anything)

Answer (score 1):

Ronan,
What you want is a simple phone-home type solution, this could be software installed on each server or independent network hardware.

Phone-Home Options (in order simplest first)

- Dedicated Site-Site VPN Tunnel using Networking (IPSEC) (OS Independent)
- Software VPN Connection (Various, IPSEC, PPTP, OpenVNP)
- SSH Tunnel (port based initiation, pending underline OS)

As for security, you would just need to prevent endpoints from communicating with each other,  a standard option on any VPN Solution

Hardware approach, Each endpoint has a IPSEC VPN Router, you will need to provide each endpoint it's own subnet to avoid conflicts unless you run tunnel-nat.

You can subnet these down further as you don't need entire class C's but for simplicity, I'll use a 255.255.255.0 Mask.

```
Datacenter - 172.16.0.0/24, server is 172.16.0.10.
Client A) 172.17.0.0/24, endpoint 172.17.0.10
Client B) 172.17.1.0/24, endpoint 172.17.1.10
Client C) 172.17.2.0/24, endpoint 172.17.2.10
Client D) 172.17.3.0/24, endpoint 172.17.3.10
Client E) 172.17.4.0/24, endpoint 172.17.4.10
Client F) 172.17.5.0/24, endpoint 172.17.5.10
```

you access rules would be something like:

```
allow 172.17.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/24
allow 172.16.0.0/24 172.17.0.0/16
deny any/any
```

Clients can all access the server, server can access clients, clients cannot access each other.

vLans don't really come into play unless you have multiple subnets on your lan that you need to segment.